# Scala `for - yield` gives Option of Tuple, but need Tuple of Option's

Tags: scala, option-type

```
object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val x: Option[Int] = Some(2)
    val y: Option[Int] = Some(3)
    val z: Option[Int] = Some(5)

    val result1 = for {
      x <- x
      y <- y
      z <- z
    } yield {
      (x + y, x + z, y + z)
    }

    println(result1)

  }
}
```

This gives `Some((5,7,8))`. If instead e.g. `val y: Option[Int] = None` then `result1` will be a `None`, too.

Yet even if we don't have `y`, we can still calculate `x + z`. So I'd rater would want the result:

```
(None,Some(7),None)
```

This can be achieved without much code by

```
import scala.util.Try
(Try(x.get + y.get).toOption, Try(x.get + z.get).toOption, Try(y.get + z.get).toOption)
```

but I guess this is to be avoided since there are exceptions involved? Another way is using many `if`s and `isDefined`s, which is rather convoluted.

So what's the best practices approach in a situation as above to get a `Tuple` of `Option`s instead of an `Option` of `Tuple`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a library like `cats`, you can utilize the `Applicative` type class:

```
import cats.Applicative

val x: Option[Int] = Some(42)
val y: Option[Int] = None
val z: Option[Int] = Some(1)

val res1 = Applicative[Option].map2(x, y)((a, b) => a + b)
 
// syntax shortand
val res2 = Applicative[Option].map2(y, z)(_ + _)

// even shorter, needs extra import
import cats.syntax.all._
val res3 = (x, z).mapN(_ + _)

(res1, res2, res3) // (None, None, Option(43))
```

This is convenient for combining collections like `Option`, `List`, `Future` etc. when you don't depend on intermediary results. You just want to sum them up, without `b` depending on the value of `a`. Such abstraction is known as an "applicative". If you do need the ability for chaining, then the abstraction you need is "monad", which is strictly more powerful than applicative due to the aforementioned chaining ability - you can have each intermediary results depend on previously computed values. When working with monads, you can use for-comprehensions, which are basically just [syntax sugar over flatmaps](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/for-comprehension#for-comprehension). For example:

```
x.flatMap(a => y.flatMap(b => z.map(c => a + b + c)))
```

or the for-comp equivalent:

```
for {
  a <- x
  b <- y
  c <- z
} yield a + b + c
```

Here's an example of flatmap step depending on previously computed value:

```
x.flatMap { a =>
  if (a == 42) y.flatMap(b => b + a)
  else y.flatMap(b => b - a)
}
```

What you tried to do with your for-comp was failing on the first encounter of None, as you noticed yourself. This is a direct consequence of the chaining I just explained. Your for-comp was working with three Options, combining them into a single Option, and this comprehension would fail as soon as one of the three values needed to produce the result was not there.

If you wanted to use for-comprehenshion (or its flatmap counterpart), instead of having one comprehension that works on the Option layer, you could instead have three smaller comprehensions, each working on the Option layer, and then you just lump them into a tuple.

For-comp style:

```
val res1 = for {
  a <- x
  b <- y
} yield a + b

val res2 = for {
  a <- y
  b <- z
} yield a + b

val res3 = for {
  a <- x
  b <- z
} yield a + b

(res1, res2, res3)
```

and flatmap style:

```
(
  x.flatMap(a => y.map(b => a + b)),
  y.flatMap(a => z.map(b => a + b)),
  x.flatMap(a => z.map(b => a + b))
)
```

If all these functional programming shennanigans are not your jam, then I guess you can just use pattern matching:

```
val x: Option[Int] = Some(42)
val y: Option[Int] = None
val z: Option[Int] = Some(1)

def sumOpts(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]) = (a, b) match {
  case (Some(valueA), Some(valueB)) => Some(valueA + valueB)
  case _ => None
}

(sumOpts(x, y), sumOpts(y, z), sumOpts(x, z))
```